# "They are quite full up this year."

Tags: phrase-meaning

Why here is used "they" instead of "it" or "there" for example? What does "they" mean here?

> "Can we go to Polseath as usual?"
> "I'm afraid not," said his mother. "**They** are quite full up this year."

Comment: "They" (often used as a gender-free singular)  and "it" are frequently interchanged in contexts involving places, organisations and the like, especially in spoken English.

Comment: *"They did so love the house at Polseath. The beach was so lovely there, too, and the bathing was fine."* They likely refers to beaches/resort houses/campsites you can rent/visit (but not this year)

Comment: Presumably either the place where the family usually stays, or holiday accommodation in Polseath in general.