# "It's quite full up this year." vs "They are quite full up this year."

Tags: dummy-pronouns

How do you choose what pronoun to use *"It"* or *"They"* if "They" is also used as a gender-free singular? Is there no any logic?

> **It's** quite full up this year.
>
> **They are** quite full up this year.

Do these sentences have absolutely the same meaning and no any difference?

Comment: It depends of the context. If you are talking about the water level in a reservoir then clearly "they are quite full" is incorrect. If it's the room reservations in a hotel, then they are synonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentences have different meanings.  The first one refers to a singular item, the second refers to multiple items.

> Look at that pond. It's quite full up this year

> Look at those ponds. They're quite full up this year.

It is possible that "they" is being used to refer to a singular person.

> My cousin just ate a whole loaf of bread, so they are quite full up.

You don't use "it" to refer to a person (unless they specifically request it)

These aren't dummy pronouns.  The dummy pronoun is usually  (alway?) "it":

> It's been fine this week.

Comment: James, I'm reading a book and there is the following dialogue there: "Can we go to Polseath as usual?" "I'm afraid not," said his mother. "They are quite full up this year."

Comment: So, if it be "It's quite full up this year" it means that Polseath is full up this year, isn't it? Or you can use "They" in relation to whole city?

Comment: "They" can't refer to the city which is singular, (also I'm not sure what it means for a city to be full) so you need to think what is the plural things that are being referred to in this sentence. They should be things that can become full, and which would make it difficult to go to Polseath if they are full.... perhaps  the **hotels** (plural) in Polsheath.  Not a dummy pronoun.

Comment: See my comment under your earlier question https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/277669/they-are-quite-full-up-this-year